# tell django not to follow foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to tell django not to follow a foreign key relationship when you instantiate a model instance? Something to put on the model itself? Something to pass to a queryset? I'd like to have a queryset that only returns instances with the foreign key id -- I don't want the instances to go off making queries to find its relatives. Something like the opposite of `select_related`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of Django is to wait until a foreign key relationship is accessed before performing a database queries to populate the related model instance.

To side-step the automatic querying for related instances, rather than accessing the ForeignKey field attribute directly, access `attribute_id`, e.g.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

# access the user id via user_id
person = Person.objects.all()[0]
print person.user_id
```

Comment: I have not been able to find this documented anywhere, but it seems like the 'wait until foreign key relationship is accessed' behavior only holds if the foreign key relationship is with a model in the same app. If the foreign key links to a model outside of its app, django will select as soon the model is instantiated. Am I wrong? This seems very bad. EDIT: Check out some test cases with debugsqlshell.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong, it doesn't matter what app the related model is in, by default information for related instances isn't retrieve until the related attribute is accessed.

Comment: Ok -- you are right. I was using django-debug-toolbar to watch the SQL that was executed. Looks like there is a bug in ddt that causes the behavior I described above (it follows the foreign key relationship if t it is outside of the current models's app). I turned ddt off and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try [defer](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#defer)

Comment: defer would not work (had my issue not been caused by a bug...see below), because I wanted the foreign key's id, I just didn't want the foreign key object itself.